# Can't enable System UI Tuner

Tags: settings, 7.0-nougat, asus-zenfone-2, lineageos

I am running Lineage OS (14.1-20170324) on my Asus Zenfone 2 (Z00A). I know that System UI Tuner can be enabled by holding up settings cog for about 10 seconds. But it is not enabling on my device.

System animations are enabled but the cog is not spinning.

> Root is enabled on my device.

Comment: See if you can locate shortcut to system UI using [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut)- wondering if the activity is working fine but is not responding to touch due to a ROM bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the *System Tuner UI* was removed starting with LineageOS 14.1, see [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/60ppql/system_ui_tuner/). The settings which were to be found there are claimed to be integrated with the standard settings – and from the screenshot of the *UI Tuner* I've seen, this indeed seems to be the case (My BQ is also running LOS 14.1, and I can't enable the *UI Tuner* either).